# SQL - Raise error in Sproc when the select result set is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to execute a stored procedure within a SQL JOB step (SQL Server 2005).
I want to Raise error and fail the job step when the result set of the stored procedure I am executing is not empty.

what my stored procedure does is --I have a select statement where the rows are displayed if the current date is equal to the date in one of the columns of a table.

```
SELECT 
Holiday_date
from tblHolidays 
where 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Holiday_date,101)
```

If the result set is empty, I want to succeed the job step and proceed with the next job step.

Any thoughts on how to get this working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) althought I can't remember if this will cause the whole job to fail, if it does try one of the warning [severity levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx).

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
  RAISERROR ('found data', 16, 1)
```

Comment: would have to be `IF @@ROWCOUNT <= 0` - raise the error when the result set **is empty**

Comment: Aye, but I read the op as wanting the error when there *are records.

Comment: Alex is right, I want to raise the error when there are records

Comment: I was able to catch the custom error message and quit the job in the Job history of the SQL JOB.  I had to choose the option while setting up the sproc exec job step under advanced options tab.  Thanks Alex!